# How to create JSON from array and map in Android?

Tags: android, json, nsarray, nsdictionary

In iOS if I have arrays and maps nested, I can call `NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject` method, and it will render it to a **JSON string**. For map, or `NSDictionary` I can use the `setValueForKey` method, for array, or `NSArray` I can use `add` method to populate with data. How is it possible in Android?

Is this approach works in Android? Does appropriate methods exist in Android?

- `NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject`
- `setValueForKey`
- `add`

Answer (score 3):

> - `NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject`

https://github.com/google/gson

GSON is a very well supported and used JSON serialisation and deserialisation library. It is very easy to use.

> - `setValueForKey`

https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

You can also manually manipulate JSON objects using the classes available in the platform itself.

> - `add`

https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html

Everything you can do in iOS you can do in Android :) Just maybe slightly differently

Comment: Why would you suggest he use Gson, and then also point him to org.json.JSONObject? Gson has its own models

Comment: I would just use GSON but I am attempting to answer his question fully by addressing all his points.

Comment: I don't see how `JSONObject` is relevant to `setValueForKey`, and how `JSONArray` is relevant to `add`

Comment: @TimCastelijns perhaps you can post your own answer? Happy to be schooled :)

Comment: So sorry to trouble you @TimCastelijns